# Syncing Audio and Video Streams with FFmpeg to Resolve Timestamp Differences

Tags: command-line, sound, video, sync, ffmpeg

I've encountered an issue with a video file where the audio and visual streams are out of sync. After some research, I've learned that this might be due to timestamp differences between the two streams. I'm wondering if it's possible to use FFmpeg and its libraries to find the timestamp difference between the audio and visual streams of the video file, and then create a new synchronized copy of the video where both streams are in perfect sync.

Could someone guide me through the process of identifying the timestamp difference between the audio and visual streams and show me how to use FFmpeg to adjust and synchronize them correctly? I'm relatively new to using FFmpeg, so a step-by-step explanation would be highly appreciated.

Thank you in advance for your help!"